# Node.js closes as I open it

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I am running a very simple script in nodejs, loading a static html file.

```
var http = require("http");
fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
});

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(1994);
```

Whenever I launch the application it immediately closes. I see the text on the console for the half second that the application launches, but then the window closes. This happens every time.

Comment: I've never seen the console window closing like that. Are you using linux terminal/windows command prompt or what to run the script? The error message would be visible after the error is thrown with these.

Comment: When debugging command-line applications in Windows, **never** doubleclick on them. Open a standalone command prompt and run them from there, "the window closes" can mean that an error occured but you don't know what it is because it closed, or because the application quit prematurely for some other reason but you wouldn't know because the window closed. Running the program manually will let you see logging output and error messages.

Comment: You have an error while reading `./index.html` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling and re-installing nodejs, and then updating the problem was solved. I think that it was simply node being new to windows with a few unaccounted for issues. The problem was a few months ago, so I forget the exact specifics. Using command prompt shells in windows leads to problems (as one can imagine.)

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably using the Node.js repl which comes with any installation of Node.js.

I get no errors when I run your code (assuming I have index.html in my directory and no error is thrown).

Try to run your code via the command line with the command`node yourscriptfilename.js`