# Node.js not working on Windows XP machine

Tags: node.js, windows-xp

I am just getting started with node.js and I have followed multiple tutorials to get it working on my Windows XP machine.

Downloaded the msi and installed with no issues, opened a command prompt and typed node -v and nothing displays. I created a folder and made a JS file with console.log('hello'); in it, changed to that directory and typed node hello.js and nothing shows.

I then added this code to the hello.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello World\n');
    }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

and ran the file from the command line again, it paused briefly and then again displayed nothing.

Been through 10 different tutorials on 10 different sites and can't find a thing to answer this question, even all the information here was no help at this point.

I have also checked the path and it is fine and rebooted the machine just in case.

Seriously stuck!

Comment: You need to set node in your Environment Variable too or your command prompt will have no idea what node is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your path to node (Environment Variable). Check the following address:

http://www.hacksparrow.com/install-node-js-and-npm-on-windows.html

This is necessary for running node from any folder in the system.

Or you can add node as an  enviroment variable in Windows XP's settings:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310519

Comment: The path is (and has been) set on the machine but still I get nothing. When I open the node.js command window and type anything node related (version, run a script etc) windows does not throw an error, literally nothing happens for a few seconds then then the command line prompt returns

Comment: are you calling node from the folder where your project is?

Comment: example: node index.js (you need to have your index.js file on the path)

Comment: I added the nodejs folder to the path c:\Program Files\nodejs. I then made a simple 'Hello World' script:

console.log("Hello World");

And saved it in that folder as hello.js

I open the node command prompt and change to the node folder and type:

node hello.js

The command prompt 'thinks' for a moment and then goes back to the prompt and nothing happens.

I even tried added the path all the way to the hello.js and tried it again and the exact same thing happened.

Frustrating the living daylights out of me!

Comment: chech this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582666/node-js-closes-as-i-open-it it may be a node issue.